# What is the correct way to check for String equality in Typescript (for Angular 4)

Tags: string, angular, typescript, equality

In Angular 4, I want to check for the current url and if it is equal to "/login" I need to submit a specific form. Here is the code:

```
 let responseString=this.router.url;
 console.log(responseString);
 if (responseString.match("/login")==null)
   this.submitForm();
```

The above code does not submit the form in all cases. There is something wrong with the if condition I guess.
Any clues?

Comment: `if (responseString === "/login")` did you try this?

Comment: match doesn't test for equality. === does that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: i'm comparing re-entered password with password. but this is always getting failed this.password1 === this.password2 in component.ts. can you please tell the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For simple string-to-string equality, you can use the `===` operator.

Comment: i'm comparing re-entered password with password. but this is always getting failed this.password1 === this.password2 in component.ts. can you please tell the answer.

Answer (score 5):

For a more flexible solution I would do

```
reponseString.includes(“login”)
```

This way you’re not stuck to the format of the url. It can be a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

use below code for reference

```
 if ( this.loginForm.value['username'] === this.username && this.loginForm.value['password'] === this.password) {
  alert(' login successfully : ' + JSON.stringify(this.loginForm.value));
} else {
  alert(' enter valid username and password ');
}
```